# Reopen "How do I represent a buy out of my team on my resume?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close, duplicates

The question has been marked as an exact duplicate of another. The current question talks about the effects of acquisition of the OP's team by another company, while the supposed question that it is a duplicate of talks about the effects of acquisition of the entire company where that OP was employed.

When making a resume, both are very different situations that need to be portrayed and therefore, I feel that the question isn't a duplicate.

Here's the question being talked about: 
[How do I represent a buy out of my team on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104670/how-do-i-represent-a-buy-out-of-my-team-on-my-resume/)

Here's the reportedly 'exact duplicate' 
[What is the accepted method of indicating a company being acquired on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-indicating-a-company-being-acquired-on-a-resume)

Furthermore, the highest-voted answer for that question says that the current company was formerly known as something else. This answer doesn't make sense to be written on a resume of the first OP because only their team was acquired; the former company still exists!

**I am requesting that this question be reopened.**

Good day.

Comment: I already commented as much, but in my view the difference doesn't substantially affect the question asked or what it's answers would look like. The scope of the acquisition is irrelevant to how it should be listed on the resume. (I wouldn't have mod-closed if I did of course.) *Perhaps* if it asked about listing the fact that the team was aquired and the OP is now working as a consultant for the same original company that'd be different but that's not what he's asking.

Comment: The issue here is that the referred duplicate is incorrect in that the answers to it treat the previous company as no longer existing, which cannot be used by the OP of this question because the company hasn't been acquired; just the team. Therefore, by referring possible future viewers of the question elsewhere, we might be making them believe something else entirely, and therefore be unhelpful. I feel we can strive to find another duplicate, and re-open the question while we search.